# How to resolve 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' Error in Passport Google OAuth 2.0 Authentication?

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

#### Expected behavior

Upon successful authentication using Google OAuth 2.0 with Passport, I expect the user to be redirected to a successful login route.

#### Actual behavior

I'm getting the `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` when trying to redirect after successful authentication using Google OAuth 2.0 with Passport. The error seems to originate from `response.redirect` within the `handleAuthenticationWithGoogleSuccess` function.

I've also tried using `` successReturnToOrRedirect: `${CURRENT_CLIENT_HOST_URL}/auth/google/success` `` without getting any other result. If I log the user within the callback, it is being returned...

#### Steps to reproduce

Here are the main snippets from my code that relate to this issue:

**Passport Service**

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import { inject, injectable } from "inversify";
import passport from "passport";
import { PassportGoogleStrategy } from "@authentication/application/strategies/google.strategy";
import { UserManagementModuleIdentifiers } from "@userManagement/dependencies/identifiers";
import { IPassportService } from "../interfaces/services.interfaces";
import { PassportLocalStrategy } from "@authentication/application/strategies/local.strategy";
import { IGetUserUseCase } from "@userManagement/modules/users/domain/interfaces/usecases.interfaces";
import { UserEntity } from "@userManagement/modules/users/domain/entities/user.entity";

export enum EnabledAuthenticationStrategies {
  GOOGLE = "google",
  JWT = "jwt",
  LOCAL = "local",
}

@injectable()
export class PassportService implements IPassportService {
  constructor(
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.PASSPORT_GOOGLE_STRATEGY)
    private readonly googleStrategy: PassportGoogleStrategy,
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.PASSPORT_LOCAL_STRATEGY)
    private readonly localStrategy: PassportLocalStrategy,
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.GET_USER_USE_CASE)
    private readonly getUserUseCase: IGetUserUseCase
  ) {
    passport.use(
      EnabledAuthenticationStrategies.GOOGLE,
      this.googleStrategy.getStrategy()
    );
    passport.use(
      EnabledAuthenticationStrategies.LOCAL,
      this.localStrategy.getStrategy()
    );

    passport.serializeUser(function (user: UserEntity, done) {
      return done(null, user.guid);
    });

    passport.deserializeUser((guid: string, done) => {
      this.getUserUseCase
        .execute(guid)
        .then((user) => {
          console.log("Deserialized User:", user);
          return done(null, user);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return done(err, null);
        });
    });
  }

  initialize = () => {
    return passport.initialize();
  };

  session = () => {
    return passport.session();
  };

  authenticate = (strategy: string, options?: object, done?: any) => {
    return passport.authenticate(strategy, options, done);
  };
}
```

**Google Strategy**

```js
import { injectable, inject } from "inversify";
import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";
import {
  ICreateUserUseCase,
  ISearchUserUseCase,
} from "@userManagement/modules/users/domain/interfaces/usecases.interfaces";
import { UserManagementModuleIdentifiers } from "@userManagement/dependencies/identifiers";
import { IUserCreatedFromValidSources } from "@userManagement/modules/users/domain/entities/user.entity";
import {
  CURRENT_SERVER_HOST_URL,
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
} from "@shared/infrastructure/config/env";

@injectable()
export class PassportGoogleStrategy {
  private strategy: GoogleStrategy;

  constructor(
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.CREATE_USER_USE_CASE)
    private readonly createUserUseCase: ICreateUserUseCase,
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.SEARCH_USER_USE_CASE)
    private readonly searchUserUseCase: ISearchUserUseCase
  ) {
    this.strategy = new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: `${CURRENT_SERVER_HOST_URL}/auth/google/success`,
      },
      async (_, __, profile, done) => {
        // Use arrow function here
        try {
          let user = await this.searchUserUseCase.execute({
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
          });

          if (!user) {
            user = await this.createUserUseCase.execute({
              email: profile.emails[0].value,
              createdFrom: IUserCreatedFromValidSources.GOOGLE,
            });
          }

          return done(null, user);
        } catch (err) {
          return done(err);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  getStrategy() {
    return this.strategy;
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```js
import {
  controller,
  httpPost,
  BaseHttpController,
  httpGet,
  request,
  response,
  next,
} from "inversify-express-utils";
import { inject } from "inversify";
import { UserManagementModuleIdentifiers } from "@userManagement/dependencies/identifiers";
import {
  ISignUpHandler,
  ILoginHandler,
} from "@authentication/domain/interfaces/handlers.interfaces";
import { verifyApiKeyMiddleware } from "@authorization/presentation/middlewares/valid-api-key.middleware";
import { IPassportService } from "@authentication/domain/interfaces/services.interfaces";
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express";
import { EnabledAuthenticationStrategies } from "@authentication/domain/services/passport.service";
import { IAuthenticationController } from "@authentication/domain/interfaces/controllers.interfaces";
import { CURRENT_CLIENT_HOST_URL } from "@shared/infrastructure/config/env";

export function sessionLogger(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  // Log session ID and user information (if available) for each request
  console.log("Session ID:", (req as any).sessionID);
  console.log("User:", req.user);

  next(); // Call the next middleware in the chain
}

@controller("/auth")
export class AuthenticationController
  extends BaseHttpController
  implements IAuthenticationController
{
  constructor(
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.SIGN_UP_HANDLER)
    private signUpHandler: ISignUpHandler,
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.LOGIN_HANDLER)
    private loginHandler: ILoginHandler,
    @inject(UserManagementModuleIdentifiers.PASSPORT_SERVICE)
    private passportService: IPassportService
  ) {
    super();
  }

  @httpPost("/signup", verifyApiKeyMiddleware)
  signUp() {
    return this.signUpHandler.handle(
      this.httpContext.request,
      this.httpContext.response
    );
  }

  @httpPost("/login")
  login() {
    return this.loginHandler.handle(
      this.httpContext.request,
      this.httpContext.response
    );
  }

  @httpGet("/google")
  authenticateWithGoogle(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.passportService.authenticate(
      EnabledAuthenticationStrategies.GOOGLE,
      { scope: ["profile", "email"] }
    )(req as any, res, next);
  }

  @httpGet("/google/success")
  handleAuthenticationWithGoogleSuccess(
    @request() req: Request,
    @response() res: Response,
    @next() next: NextFunction
  ) {
    this.passportService.authenticate(
      EnabledAuthenticationStrategies.GOOGLE,
      {
        failureRedirect: "/login",
        successReturnToOrRedirect: `${CURRENT_CLIENT_HOST_URL}/auth/google/success`,
      },
      (error, user, info) => {
        // here use res directly, not via the callback args
        res.redirect(`${CURRENT_CLIENT_HOST_URL}/auth/google/success`);
      }
    )(req as any, res, next);
  }

  @httpGet("/me")
  getCurrentUser(req: Request, res: Response) {
    // Log session information using the sessionLogger middleware
    sessionLogger(req, res, () => {
      if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        // User is authenticated, return the user's information
        const user = req.user;
        res.json(user);
      } else {
        // User is not authenticated, return an appropriate response
        res.status(401).json({ error: "Not authenticated" });
      }
    });
  }

  @httpPost("/logout")
  logout(req: Request) {
    req.logout((err: any) => {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error if needed
        console.error("Error occurred during logout:", err);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**server.ts**

```js
import "reflect-metadata";
import * as Sentry from "@sentry/node";
import {
  connectCriticalInfrastructure,
  disconnectCriticalInfrastructure,
} from "@shared/infrastructure/helpers/critical-infrastructure.helpers";
import { setupGracefulShutdown } from "@shared/infrastructure/helpers/server.helpers";
import { errorHandler } from "@shared/presentation/middlewares/error-handling.middleware";
import cors from "cors";
import express from "express";
import helmet from "helmet";
import morgan from "morgan";
import session from "express-session";

import { IPassportService } from "@authentication/domain/interfaces/services.interfaces";
import { GlobalDependenciesIdentifiers } from "@shared/infrastructure/dependencies/identifiers";
import { getRootContainer } from "@shared/infrastructure/dependencies/root-container";
import { initializeLoggingInfrastructure } from "@shared/infrastructure/helpers/secondary-infrastructure.helpers";
import { InversifyExpressServer } from "inversify-express-utils";
import { mainRouter } from "shared/presentation/routes/main-router";
import { JWT_SECRET } from "@shared/infrastructure/config/env";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let server = new InversifyExpressServer(getRootContainer());

server.setConfig((app) => {
  initializeLoggingInfrastructure(app);

  const passport = getRootContainer().get<IPassportService>(
    GlobalDependenciesIdentifiers.USER_MANAGEMENT.PASSPORT_SERVICE
  );
  passport.initialize(); // Initialize Passport

  // Middlewares
  app.use(
    session({
      secret: JWT_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' },
    })
  );
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use("/", mainRouter);
  
  app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());
  app.use(errorHandler);

  // Start server
  connectCriticalInfrastructure()
    .catch(async (error) => {
      console.error(
        "AN ERROR OCCURED WHILE CONNECTING CRITICAL INFRASTRUCTURE DEPENDENCIES: ",
        error
      );
      await disconnectCriticalInfrastructure();
      process.exit(1);
    })
    .then(() => {
      const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.info(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}.`);
      });

      // Setting up graceful shutdown
      setupGracefulShutdown(server, disconnectCriticalInfrastructure);
    });
});

server.build();
```

#### Environment

- Operating System: macOS Monterey 12.3.1
- Node version: v16.16.0
- Passport version: passport@0.6.0
- Passport-google-oauth2 version: passport-google-oauth20@2.0.0

I have attempted to troubleshoot the issue myself but have been unable to identify the root cause. I suspect the error may be related to the order of setting headers or the usage of Passport middleware in the `handleAuthenticationWithGoogleSuccess` function.

I am seeking advice, solutions, or any suggestions on how to resolve the 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT' error and achieve successful authentication using Google OAuth 2.0 with Passport. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!